# Disable keyboard tab indexing for whole app WPF Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there any way to disable tab indexing for whole app (all controls) in WPF using KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation?

Comment: With 'whole app' you mean all windows you're possibly going to create with all their contained elements?

Comment: Yes. Actually, all controls inside MainWindow.xaml (example : UserControl, Grid, Button, TextBox etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another potentially safer approach would be to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the window programmatically:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => 
        {
            e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Tab;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Wondering how this will effect if I want to do anything by Tab press other than tab indexing

Comment: Like what? This will effectively swallow TAB key presses and don't process them.

Comment: This seems to be more safer. Marking it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution. Placing KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" on header section inside MainWindow.xaml solved it

Comment: Thats what I investigated too at first... but instead of hitting tab first, just set the focus within your application and re-try hitting tab. There are some controls that don't really care for this property. Granted: i just tested it with a project where I utilize the DataGridControl from XCeed extended wpf toolkit. So it might be their implementation not following the standard :)